# C# Repeater dynamic Button

Tags: c#, dynamic, controls

I am using repeater to generate the button control.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDoc" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<div style="...">
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="button_Click" />
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

For example, I can generate 4 buttons. However, how can I implement
the program inside each of the button?

when btnUpload1 clicked, it will upload files into Folder1,
when btnUpload2 clicked, it will upload files into Folder2

I know there is a way that create a Table in the web form, and then
dynamically put the generated button inside the table cells... But I
have lots of DIVs with styling, so I don't want to use a table to
place the dynamic buttons.

Thanks for help.

Comment: How do you determine which button redirects to what site? Why not use a `hyperlink` and set the `href` to the site you want?

Comment: I want to add the Attributes.Add("Tag", uploadedFileID) for each generated control

Comment: So that, when the button click event happened, i can get the Tags and continue the job...

Comment: The above links just an example, actually I need to determine the Upload Path when the button clicked, and then upload documents into that folder.

Comment: That's totally different than redirecting to some random websites.

Comment: Oh sorry that's my fault. I just want to add the attributes 'Tag' and click event into the above dynamic button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me now, I used the LinkButton instead of Button.
Also added OnItemCommand="ItemCommand" in repeater.
And finally it will goto ItemCommand event when LinkButton clicked.
It gets the value from CommandArgument which set in dynamic LinkButton

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemCommand="ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("lbtnUploadCommandArgument")%>' CommandName="ButtonEvent">Upload Files</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


protected void ItemCommand(Object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
string[] arr_Para = ((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).CommandArgument.Split(';');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you dynamically add buttons to the web form, you can track what each button should be doing and then process that URL in a common click event, like the hackish example below.

```
Dictionary<System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button, string> ButtonToURIMap = new Dictionary<System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button, string>();
private void AddButtonToForm()
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button myWebButton = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button();
    //Initialize/Style your button here.
    myWebButton.Click +=myWebButton_Click;
    ButtonToURIMap.Add(myWebButton, "http://www.google.com/");
}

void myWebButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button callingButton = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)sender;
        if ( ButtonToURIMap.ContainsKey(callingButton))
        {
            string uri = ButtonToURIMap[callingButton];
            //code you execute from here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is below.

**in your codebehind**

```
Protected Sub MyPointsRepeater_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles MyPointRepeater.ItemCommand
    arg = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(";"c)
End Sub
```

**in your Aspx page**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyPointRepeater" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>

<label class="ConferenceName"><%#Eval("Conference Name").ToString()%></label><br />
<label class="RegistrationId"><%#Eval("CPD Points / Hours").Tostring() %></label>
<label class="Type"><%#Eval("Type").ToString()%></label>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCustomize" Text="Download Certificate"  CommandName="Customize" CssClass="fontLight"
                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("R_Id").Tostring() + ";" + Eval("Conf_Id").Tostring() + ";" + Eval("Reg Id").Tostring() + ";" + Eval("CPD Points / Hours").Tostring() + ";" + Eval("Type").Tostring()%>'  runat="server" /> 

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```